# With Insomnia, is there a way of going back to a previous request?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, curl, url, ergonomics, insomnia

For clarification, I'm talking about the REST/URL entry app [Insomnia](https://insomnia.rest/), a Postman alternative, or a way of doing cURL requests easily.

So for my simple REST request needs, this is just pretty much what I need. A lot of the competition (Kibana, etc.) is a bit annoying and complicated.

But one thing I was expecting to find is a way to go back to a previously executed request. So I might do one `GET ...` and then a `POST ...` and I would hope to find a simple way to repeat the `GET` request. So this would be a bit like a command line terminal: in all systems you can track back and repeat previous commands with minimal trouble.

But I can't find anything like that in Insomnia. Does anything like that exist?

***Later***
Strangely, on the preferences page/dialog, tab Keyboard, there are two options, "Show Recent Requests" and "Show Recent Requests (Previous)" (NB what's the difference???). But neither of these hotkeys appear to do anything at all. Will probably have to contact them via Github. All quite mysterious.

Comment: Not sure if this helps you but I gave up on cURL and moved to c# .net core stuff.  It works beautifully on Linux and Windows and managing the commands have been much more simple from my perspective.  Just a thought.  I am sure it can be used directly from PowerShell but I have never done that.